# makeStyles ошибка typescript - This expression is not callable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mui

Помогите разобраться с ошибкой useStyles
Пишет - This expression is not callable.
Type 'never' has no call signatures.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj7Qq.png

`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';

interface IHoriz {
    shag:number
}

export default function HorizontalStepperWithError(props:IHoriz) {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    root: {
      "& .MuiStepIcon-active": { color: "RoyalBlue" },
      "& .MuiStepIcon-completed": { color: "green" },
      // "& .Mui-disabled .MuiStepIcon-root": { color: "cyan" }
    }
  }));
  const c = useStyles();

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%',marginBottom:-34 }}>
      <Stepper activeStep={props.shag} className={c.root} style={{background:'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}}>
            <Step>
              <StepLabel ><Typography style={{fontSize:10}}>Заполнение</Typography></StepLabel>
            </Step>
            <Step>
            <StepLabel ><Typography style={{fontSize:10}}>Проверка</Typography></StepLabel>
          </Step>
      </Stepper>
    </Box>
  );
}`
```

Comment: Первая ошибка - нет кода, скрин не виден(если там код, то он должен быть размещен текстом). + Сама ошибка так же должна быть указана в вопросе текстом. Если есть стектрейс, то и он тоже. Чем больше подробностей, тем быстрее помогут

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вот по этому, и нужно что бы код отправлялся текстом. У тебя же на скрине нету половины кода. А ещё описания проблемы тоже нет. Сорри, за то что написал ответ, просто репутации ещё не накопил

Comment: дополнил, хотя казалось бы самое главное выделил

Comment: Проверьте, что у вас лежит в `useStyles` - есть ощущение, что это вообще не функция, а если это и она, то она хочет входящие аргументы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Был не правильный импорт, надо так:

```
// Re-export with a default theme
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


// Original module with no default theme
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
```